# Enumerar registros por bloque en mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de crear una consulta para que enumere los registros cada cierto número de filas, algo como lo siguiente:

```
| rownum| dato | descripcion | 
|-------|------|-------------|
|   1   |   1  | Descripcion |      
|   2   |   1  | Descripcion |      
|   3   |   1  | Descripcion |         
|   4   |   2  | Descripcion |  
|   5   |   2  | Descripcion |   
|   6   |   2  | Descripcion |   
|   7   |   3  | Descripcion |   
|   8   |   3  | Descripcion |
|   9   |   3  | Descripcion |
```

Ya entendí como enumerar todas las filas con un número consecutivo, el código que estoy usando es este:

```
SELECT  @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum
,'' as dato 
, t1.descripcion 
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r,tabla t1
```

Si pudieran guiarme que investigar se los agradecería!

Comment: Podrias crear un procedimiento almacenado y dentro del mismo recorrer los datos con algun bucle iterativo como un "for" o un "while" de esta manera podrías añadir lógica para enumerar los registros cada cierto numero de filas. Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo

Comment: Bienvenido blackleaf29 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿De que dato dependería la numeración de cada grupo?

Answer (score 1):

Divide el número de fila por el número filas que necesites, y redondea:

```
, ceil(@rownum/3) as dato
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! es justo lo que necesito :)

Comment: @blackleaf29 Si esta respuesta ayuda a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, puedes marcarla como respuesta, revisa [tour], saludos.